# Need 15 minute delay alarm

Tags: microcontroller, relay, timer, 555

I need to use electronics to make a:

12v, ~60db, ~3second intermittent beep, ~15 minute delayed alarm, started by toggle switch, stopped by toggle switch.

Analog or digital, whichever is smaller.

Help with part selection and layout would be wonderful, but advice on a direction to explore would also help.

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: A single CMOS 555 can handle the delay time.  The problem is the output.  Other solutions do everything, but need a 14 pin package instead of 8.  What is your skill set for hand-soldering surface mount IC's?

Comment: Maybe consider using a 8-pin MCU like the PIC for a precise 15-minute timer? They are also cost-effective though they typically require a PICkit for programming.

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it is not a forum. And please read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, adding clarification asked for in comments and first answers. -- What possibilities do you have? Do you have access to some MCU development environment? Do you have digital or analog parts lying around? If so, which? How much time would you like to invest to learn new stuff?

Comment: Here is an interesting part that might do everything with very few components: https://www.allelectronics.com/mas_assets/media/allelectronics2018/spec/L4620.pdf

Comment: Rick DuRapau - Hi, (a) I appreciate you've tried to follow the site rules by making edits. However, fundamentally, your question is not in a state that is suitable for Stack Exchange (SE) - it is just too broad. A "whole project" question like this, is not specific enough to be a good fit on SE. A more typical *forum* may be more suited to the type of ongoing to-and-fro discussion which it seems your question needs, but which is explicitly *discouraged* in Q&A on the main site here.

Comment: (continued) (b) Regarding the [latest significant edit](/revisions/679744/3) to this question. It has now become misleading by omission, as well as too broad. It's misleading because that edit removed the explanation about the constraint of the limited space for your circuit. Yet it asks for "help with ... layout" which would *rely* on knowing about that constraint. That's just one way (of several) that the question is not currently in a suitable state, as people can waste time due to not having the information which was removed.

Comment: (continued) (c) It seems that the edits were trying to make the question short but, fundamentally, it's a (too) broad question asking for a complete design, with significant mechanical constraints, even if it is asked using few words. (d) It seems clarification questions were asked in comments and in [an answer](/a/679747) but few of them received responses. The last significant edit is still asking effectively the same question, without acknowledging that an answer was already given to the previous version of the question. This indicates no progress is being made. That isn't good.

Comment: (continued) (e) On SE, when someone writes an answer, if it doesn't meet your requirements you should respond in a *comment* on that answer & explain where you need further help. Just editing the question after an answer was posted makes things *less* clear, as it suggests the given answer was unsuitable but there's no comment on that answer explaining *why*. || I see you made another edit while I was typing this, saying you can't make the question more focused - that just confirms the "disconnect", unfortunately. You see the question as focused, but we see it as too broad.

Comment: (continued) It may seem a focused question to you, but it isn't. It is "under constrained" and it's unclear why the answer & comments already given aren't enough. Site members already gave "*advice on a direction to explore*". SE just isn't a good fit for broad "whole project" questions, as I mentioned. || When you get to the stage of asking about behaviour of a specific component, or a specific schematic, then with that level of detail we should be able to help. As I said, a discussion-oriented electronics forum seems to be more suitable for this current question. Thanks.

Comment: Rick - I don't think Stackex has any kind of DM, PM, IM, or Conversation function.  You can contact me at https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/

Comment: @AnalogKid and all - I've setup [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148266/discussion-on-question-by-rick-durapau-need-15-minute-delay-alarm), where Rick and other site members can discuss the problem. As usual, if discussions lead to improvements that make the question suitable for the site, then please edit the question and vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

15 minutes is a loooong time for a single R-C timer circuit.  It's at the edge of what a standard (bipolar) 555 can do repeatedly.  A CMOS 555 can handle the delay time.  The problem is the output polarity before and after triggering.  There are three output periods - before triggering, during the timing period, and after the timing period.  In terms of logic levels, what you want is low, low, high (or high, high, low - the drive voltage to the beeper can work either way).  With a standard 555 monostable circuit, what you are limited to is low, high, low.

Other solutions do everything, but need a 14 pin package instead of 8.  With a CD4093, you get everything you've described, with about the same number if discrete R's and C's.  I'll update this answer with a schematic.

Please update your question with more information:

How loud does the beeper have to be.  Loudness requires size.  Also, intermittent beeping or a constant tone?

Once the button has been pressed and released, and the 15 minutes is up, and the beeper is going continuously, then what?  Does it go until power is removed?  Does it go until the button is pressed again? then sits waiting for another button press to restart the cycle?  If so, many will recommend a microcontroller for that "complex" a pattern, but I think it still can fit in one logic IC.

What is your skill set for hand-soldering a surface mount IC, and reading a schematic?

UPDATE:

Here is a first-pass schematic that will do what has been described so far.  Once you've got some perf-board cut to shape and the decoupling capacitor (C4) in place, assembly time should be around 60 to 90 minutes for 35 solder points.

R1-C1 is a power-on reset to make sure the circuit powers up in the quiet state.  R2-C2 set the 15 minute delay period.  When C2 has charged up to a high enough voltage, it enables R3-C3-U1C, a 1 Hz oscillator that drives the beeper.  This makes an approx. once-per-second beep.  This was not requested, but took only two components to include (the gate already was in the circuit).  In case there is any residual charge in C2 when power is applied, D1 provides a rapid discharge path.  U1D is unused, with its inputs terminated.

The original post says nothing about what to do once the circuit is beeping.  If a Reset function is needed, that is done by adding a second switch in parallel with C1.  Also, if the beeper requires more than about 4 mA, a small signal MOSFET can be added as a driver.

Note that the values for R2-C2 and R3-C3 are approximate.  A common problem with long-time R-C delay circuits is that both the tolerance and temperature coefficient of an aluminum electrolytic capacitor are poor.  If this is for a commercial product, there are other ways to get more repeatable performance.

[image]

Comment: Like the approach, but I'm also in the microcontroller camp, because writing such s controller as firmware strikes me as easier - by orders of magnitude - than learning the necessary digital logic design.

Comment: Compared to learning a development system, language, compiler, and programmer . . . . . . AFTER you learn enough to select which uC to use.  AND you still have to wire up at least a minimal circuit.  IMHO, size is the *only* advantage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It all depends on your skills. Software engineers will go the MCU route, hardware engineers the timer route, people like me knowing both worlds will decide on other reasons (untold requirements, costs, parts at hand, mood, ...) Unfortunately there is no single correct answer.

Comment: That's the thing, the minimal circuit with a microcontroller has two components: the microcontroller and a decoupling cap. Compare that to a discrete timer with any of the requirements like resettability or producing an oscillation for a piezo buzzer, and the software solution quickly becomes the one with the less involved hardware as well!

Comment: If you can, or want to, type.

Comment: See UPDATE that includes a schematic.

Comment: @AnalogKid (If you can, or want to, type.) ???

Comment: For a small project like this, you can use a uC and create the "circuit" in code (typing) or you can use logic chips and other components and do the circuit by soldering wires and pins.  So the question to the OP is this: which is more fun for you (or more within your skill set), to solder or to type?

Comment: @AnalogKid & marcusmuller: thank you gentlemen for trying to help me. I took the tour as suggested by busybee and redited the question. I thought it was in the correct format. Cannot figure how to make it any more succint. Is the denial done by AI, possibly? I work in the day on my prototype and then study up on electronics at night. It's slow going  for my old inelastic brain. I am making my way thru te comments.